# Magento2 after placing order success page showing error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, orders, order-success-page

I have tried to place an order with simple and configurable product but after placing in success page i am getting below error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Simple::getConfigurableAttributeCollection() in /var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Helper/Product/Options/Loader.php:52 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/ReadHandler.php(48): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options\Loader->load(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor)) #1 /var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read/ReadExtensions.php(48): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\ReadHandler->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array) #2 /var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read.php(117): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Read\ReadExtensions->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array) #3 /var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(61): Magento\Frame in /var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Helper/Product/Options/Loader.php on line 52
```

Please help me to fix this

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple product that is handled like a configurable product.

This leads to the error that `getConfigurableAttributeCollection()` is called on a simple product, which does not have that method of course.

I assume that you imported products or created some of them programmatically? You could check your database if all products that should have configurable attributes actually have "type_id=configurable" in the `catalog_product_entity` table.

If this does not work, please add some more data to your question: does it always occur with the same product, how was this product created, how does it look in the database?